# ActiveRecord conditions Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this:

```
SectionHistory.find(:all, :conditions => ["id=? and (name!=? or code!=?)", sec.id, sec.name, sec.code])
```

And I get the error *"The character "!" following "and (name!=? or code" is not valid"*

if my condition string is just *"id=? and (name!=?)"* it's OK

We're using DB2.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's SQL; try:

```
"id=? and not (name=? and code=?)"
```

Comment: This worked - thanks (although the != approach worked in our DB2 client)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how rails handles the conditions but if they are passed straight to the database engine then is != valid syntax for DB2.

You could try <> and see if that works